# GeoNode/GeoServer default permissions on upload

Tags: geoserver, geonode, geoserver-geofence

I have taken over management of an existing GeoNode/GeoServer instance and I am trying to find out how GeoNode is setting the permissions on each layer I upload. We have several groups, and on uploading a new layer (using the GeoNode upload form), some of these groups are already added to the permissions with the "Download" permission, and "Registered Members" is set to None. In the Apache logs I can see a bunch of GET, PUT and DELETE requests are made to the `/geoserver/rest/geofence/rules` endpoint, and the rules do appear in the geofence on GeoServer. How is GeoNode setting these rules?

Running GeoNode version 4.0.3

Comment: I believe this is the cause:

https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/issues/11576